# Apache Event + PHP FPM and allow URL Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I have been using Apache prefork and have been using .htaccess files to rewrite the URL.

I now want to move to Apache event and PHP FPM but I cannot see any way to rewrite the URL.
I am aware of .user.ini files but cannot see anything in there that will do it either.

Is there a way to use URL rewrite with MPM FCGI?

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
#ignore files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#ignore directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#pass everything else to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /php/index.php?_view=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ /php/index.php?_view=index [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have you considered this https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/apache-fastcgi-php-fpm-mod_rewrite.58086/?

Comment: Jay, I do not see how that answers my question.  I have tried putting these rules in the apache conf file instead of a .htaccess file but I get the same 500 page as a result.